# Как получить токен юзера вк в андройд приложении?

Tags: java, вконтакте, auth

Стоит задача получить токен юзера вк 
Будет два поля логин:пасс , юзер будет вводить и потом приложение должно получать токен для дальнейшего использования

Comment: вк вроде старается уйти от такой авторизации. Тут либо костылями, либо отправлять запрос в техподдержку вк и они могут открыть эту возможность, если им это будет интересно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для работы с андроид у Вконтакте есть более менее удобная библиотека (https://vk.com/dev/android_sdk). Там без проблем найдете авторизацию и работу с API